# how to get beamer theme like this?

Tags: beamer

When I first see the following, it is the best theme that I've seen.

I want to get theme like this. How can I use theme like this?

[Bayesian Nonparametrics Part II, Peter Orbanz](http://stat.columbia.edu/~porbanz/talks/MLSS12_2.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Looks like `Boadilla` to me. See [Beamer theme matrix](http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me that none of the [standard themes](http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/) fits this exact layout, so you'll just have to take the closest and adapt it yourself to your needs. Here's a start:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
\usefonttheme{structuresmallcapsserif}


\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Overview}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Constructing nonparameteric Bayesian models
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Hierarchical and dependent models
        \item Representations
        \item Exchangeability
      \end{itemize}
      \item Asymptotics
     \end{enumerate}
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}
     \begin{center}
     \huge{\textsc{New models from old ones}}
     \end{center}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]